# How to get a listNode as a result in python

Tags: python, dictionary, linked-list

So i started learning about listNodes or linked lists in python and created one;

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next


class LinkedNode:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.size = 0

  def add(self, data):
    self.head = Node(data, self.head)
    self.size += 1
```

It works fine but how can i get a listNode in python as the result of this node.

What i mean is a list node looks like this;

```
{val: 'some_val', next: {val: 'other_val', next{...}}}
```

In js, when we print the instance of the list node class, it gets the result in the same format but, in python when i tried the same;

```
ln = LinkedNode()
print(ln)
```

It gives this;
<**main**.LinkedNode object at 0x7fe191576400>

Comment: you may implement the `__str__` method of a class to print an object in the format you wish. Would that solve the problem ? or are you looking for something more than the print format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make your instance print something more useful.

For instance, you could add a method that will produce a dict, because dictionaries are printed in an output format that is similar to what you ask for:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def asdict(self):
        return  { "data": self.data, "next": self.next and self.next.asdict() }
```

So now when you do this:

```
print(Node(1).asdict())
```

... you'll get:

```
{'data': 1, 'next': None}
```

When you also add such a method to the `LinkedNode` class:

```
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)
        self.size += 1

    def asdict(self):
        return self.head and self.head.asdict()
```

...you can do:

```
lst = LinkedNode()
lst.add(1)
lst.add(2)

print(lst.asdict())
```

And that will output:

```
{'data': 2, 'next': {'data': 1, 'next': None}}
```

And finally, if you want this output to be the default that `print` will use when you just do `print(lst)`, then define `__repr__` (or `__str__`) on the class:

```
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)
        self.size += 1

    def asdict(self):
        return self.head and self.head.asdict()

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.asdict())
```

Now you can do `print(lst)` without calling `.asdict()` explicitly, and get that same output.

Comment: Though this returned something very similar to what i wanted, but that is not of the type ListNode

Comment: How did you check the type?

Comment: Actually i am solving a problem on leetcode. This is the only step remaining. The result needs to be of type ListNode

Comment: So then your question is not about printing?

Comment: I think i got it. marking your question as accepted.

Comment: I think yes, it is about priting (not that sure) but i think i have to do things as per a given class not outside that.

Comment: Typically in LeetCode you get data as an instance of the predefined class, and you should return an instance of that class. No printing is involved. If you have a question about a specific LeetCode assignment and a problem in getting your solution accepted, I suggest you ask a new question about that, providing your code, the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Also i was taking the error message in a little non-sense way. I was taking ListNode as something in-built in python but that was actually a class according to which i have to return the result.

Comment: thanks for your help. BTW i solved it. Also as i was not aware about it, that is why i didn't posted the leetcode problem